# Is the Mean Absolute Percentage Error calculated correctly?

Tags: statistics

I made a model based on raw data and I wanted to check how accurate the model was using the Mean Absolute Percentage Error. I'm pretty sure I calculated it correctly but my teacher said the percentage error seemed too large. This is what the model function with the raw/original data looks like:

[image]

And for my MAPE I got 32%.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you look at the graph, you have differences on the order of 0.01, which are divided by values on the order of 0.1. This means you are finding the mean of values on the order of 0.1 (or 10%), so yes, I'd say your result looks too high. It looks to me like your MAPE should be around 10% or less. Are you dividing by the number of samples you've used to get your MAPE, or are you simply summing them?

It's hard to answer your question because you haven't said how you calculated MAPE.

Comment: Thanks for the input. 1) I calculated the absolute error by doing (actual value-model value)/actual value 2) I found the sum of all of the values 3) Multiplied the number by 100 4) Divided the value by the number of data points (in this case, 281).

Comment: Hmmm...it sounds like you're doing it correctly. Perhaps the data values near 0 are skewing the result? Have you tried removing the data values very close to 0 as a sanity check?

Comment: I just looked at the values near 0 on my table and I think you're right! The absolute error value suddenly goes up to 7. Should I therefore calculate the MAPE without the values? Or is there another solution?

Comment: Well gee that's a hard one! Is it for an assignment? MAPE is known to give skewed results for data that is very close to 0. Have you zero meaned the data yourself? Presumably sea level doesn't go below 0? Or does it?! If the data doesn't need to be zero meaned I would shift it back to where it was originally, & find MAPE for those values. If it needs to be shifted down to sit around 0 then I would be tempted to report 2 results, one including values near 0 & one excluding those values.

Comment: one last question, why do the results get skewed near 0?

Comment: Because you're dividing by values very close to 0, which causes very large changes in the sum. This should be avoided where possible. See http://www.forecastpro.com/Trends/forecasting101August2011.html for a summary of weaknesses of MAPE.